# Cannot update an object using Entity Framework with Concurrency Fixed enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, concurrency

I will be more specific here..
This is a strange problem and really, i am not understanding why this is happening..

In my data model every table has a column of type rowversion, and in my EDM (Entity Data Model) i enabled version to be my rowversion and maps exacly with my column rowversion in database.

Here is the problem.

```
1) I List items
2) I go update one item, (supose with id 4)
3) I send to the form in a hiddenfield the value of the rowversion
4) Someone updated in database some field in id 4 (making the rowversion to change)
5) I update the new values
6) i Convert string data with rowversion to byte[]
7) I get the object with primary key from the database and affect all properties of the object returned from database with model binded object that come from the form post including the rowversion!
8) I invoke SaveChanges()
9) The Problem!
```

I go to profiler and i see that the query that is build contains the Newer version and not the older (not that i affected from the post form to the object that come from the database).

For me appears that EF when is building is using the newVersion in some place, and not uses the current value that controls concurrency in the object..

Somebody know what it is happening????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my workaround..
for persistance ignorant:

```
       public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity Entity) where TEntity : class {
            ObjectStateEntry entry = _Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(Entity);
            entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);
            entry.AcceptChanges();
            entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);
        }
```

The essence is..

POCO don't notify the context for changes, so when i update an entity, the entry still remains unchanged.

```
1) I get the entry with Entity passed in the method
2) I change the state to Modified
3) I call AcceptChanges.. (note that in step 2 i changed the state to modified, so AcceptChanges now copies the CurrentValues to OriginalValues.. - Looks that implementation of AcceptChanges just procede if the state are different than Unchanged and makes sence)
4) I got the values copied but the default behavior of acceptChanges is let the state Unchanged..
5) I change the state to modified, so the SaveChanges can build the Update Command.
```

Answer (score 0):

The EF tracks two values for every property: The value originally read from the DB, and the new value you assign.

For the concurrency token / row version, it always uses the *original* value in the WHERE when doing the update. This does make sense if you think about it, but it doesn't work for your situation.

In your Step 7, you get the **new** value of the timestamp, created during the update in step 4. So that's what appears in the `WHERE` clause. Updating the property of the entity doesn't fix this, because that changes the "current" value of the property, not the "originally read" value.

Here's a workaround:

```
// get updated object from DB, with "newer" concurrency token/timestamp
var myFoo = myContext.Foos.Single(f => f.Id == id);
// assign the "current" value of ConcurrencyToken
myFoo.ConcurrencyToken = concurrencyToken; 
// now copy the "current" value you just assigned to the "originally read from DB" 
// value, overwriting the ConcurrencyToken value you read from DB
var ose = Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(myFoo);
ose.AcceptChanges(); 
// assign rest of properties
myFoo.SomeOtherProperty = someOtherValue;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I understand.. but i am using an IRepository interface, and i just expose the methods by interface, i don't have direct access to the manager :/

Comment: it is true, is a workaround, we understand the problem, but will pollute my code because this is used in very places in my services

Comment: You can: 1) pass the concurrency token to the repository separately, 2) pass DTOs or edit models to the repository 3) use POCO entities and handle this inside the entity, 4) pick some other solution. You don't have to use my code as-is. Just apply the general plan of the solution to the design you have.

Comment: i am debugging my entry and when i apply AcceptChanges() the current values are not copied to original values..

Comment: Works for me (I use this in production code). How are you testing this? What is the state of the entity before and after `AcceptChanges()`

Comment: hmmm.. i am using POCO so, the state of the entity is unchanged.

Comment: The sequence of my code is this: i get from database and EF builds for me the object, causing a new ObjectStateEntry to be attached on the context, with state Unchanged. When i change some properties, because i am using POCO, the state remains Unchanged... After this i find the entry ObjectStateEntry and invoke AcceptChanges().. and what i see is that CurrentValues are not copied to OriginalValues... I can see to that State remains Unchanged!

Comment: If you're using "pure POCOs" then you may need to manually tell EF to detect changes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456854.aspx

Comment: DetectChanges is a heavy method that sincronize all entries in the Context, calling this method when i'm updating entity by entity will cause me a big trouble.. See my workaround below